# Which gigabit NICs are supported by Ubuntu out of the box?

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I have an issue with my [rtl8169 gigabit NIC](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/extremly-slow-samba-536370/). Which gigabit NICs are supported out of the box by Ubuntu lucid?

Comment: I have an rtl8169 that is working fine, but I don't use Samba.  Are you seeing that mentioned issue specifically?  NICs are one thing that almost all of them work on Linux, so you can usually grab any off the shelf.

Comment: well, it seems to be the problem, since i did many tests resulting in slow transfer (the everywhere mentioned 2MB/s), not only with samba

altough a windows box gets around 8MB/s
the nic would be one possibility i can think of
but keep in mind, the problem i have is slow transfer
networking, like internet,dns,... works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of network cards that are supported by Ubuntu:
[Wired Network Cards](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsWiredNetworkCards)

The list is broken down by vendor. If you click on a vendor it will take you to a list of that vendors cards that are supported/unsupported.

It seems that your Realtek RTL-8169 is supported, but it doesn't list which version of Ubuntu it is confirmed to work with.